# Drop empty variables when importing spss into Stata

Tags: stata

I have an spss dataset that has ~27000 variables, but only ~500 include any values. The rest are blank for every observation. I'm using Stata 16 IC (maxvar 2048), so I'm unable to import the dataset. Is there any way to import the data with only those variables that aren't empty? Thanks!

Comment: Use can use Excel Filters and filter out blank cells.

Comment: You posted on Statalist and go nowhere with this, I guess because few people there even use SPSS, let alone are expert on it. I don't think there are many people here active on the Stata tag who use SPSS either. So, I am left with a silly question: isn't there a way to drop empty variables in SPSS?

Comment: It's better to ask this question on https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spss

Comment: @greenmarker I disagree with that advice. On Cross Validated this is all too likely to be closed as off-topic.

Comment: "Cross Validated is a question and answer site for people interested in statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, and data visualization"

Comment: If the only access to Stata is to IC, then there might be a painful solution in terms of reading in batches of variables, dropping ones that are all empty, and then applying `merge` to the results. Finding someone with a copy of Stata SE or MP is in principle another answer.

Comment: @greenmarker Sure, you can cite that, but I am a long-term active member of CV with enough reputation to vote to close. Questions like this one get closed, and quickly. https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic  is more specific. This question is pure data management, not statistics. I would recommend to the OP finding an SPSS support site and asking how to drop empty variables.

Comment: I already got rejected from Cross Validated. Thanks for the thoughts, guys.

Comment: Also, I don't know anything about SPSS (the data weren't created by me, but by the federal government). I downloaded a trial copy of SPSS, but I'm kind of lost in it.

Comment: I think I can get the data in SAS as well, if that's helpful. But I can't get it in Stata.